# Is there a way to change screen from an ListView Item?

Tags: listview, flutter, listviewitem

I have to make a flutter app in which my HomeScreen page is populated with an ListView ( this widget is populated with data from firebase database ) and I've done this but now I have to make an onPressed event. I've done this with InkWell but now I don't know how to make every item do a different function.

This is my code:

//Main Screen

```
    class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Function> itemFunctions = [
      () {
      print("1");
      Navigator.pop(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Antique()));},
          () {Navigator.pop(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Mediterana()));},
      () {Navigator.pop(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SuperKebab()));},

    ];
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("e-Radauti Restaurante"),
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: _firebaseRef.onValue,
              builder: (context, snap) {
                if (snap.hasData &&
                    !snap.hasError &&
                    snap.data.snapshot.value != null) {
                  Map data = snap.data.snapshot.value;
                  List item = [];
                  data.forEach(
                      (index, data) => item.add({"key": index, ...data}));
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: item.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(
                        child: Container(
                          child: InkWell(
                            child: MediaQuery.removePadding(context: context,removeTop: true,removeBottom: true, child: Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                width: 100,
                                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                    placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                        CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                    imageUrl:
                                    item[index]["photoUrl"].toString(),
                                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                        Icon(Icons.error),
                                  ),
                              ),
                                Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(item[index]["name"]),
                                    Text(item[index]["description"]),
                                  ],
                                )
                              ]
                            ),),
                        
                          onTap: () {itemFunctions[index]; print("Clicked item nr $index");}
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              })
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: This is one of the screen that I want to change to

```
    class SuperKebab extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Meniu Super Kebab"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Revin!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: It seems that my click on items works but the functions in `<code>List < Function >... </code>` aren't called.

This is my log output

[image]

This is my firebase database structure:

[image]

So basically my first item is Antique, second one is Mediterana, and the last one is SuperKebab

And I want when I click on the first item (antique) to navigate to Antique screen, when I click on the second item I want it to navigate to Mediterana screen and so on.

I think a method will be to make a single function and populate that with data from firebase storage depending on the case.

Comment: how many items max you will have in the Listview?

Comment: @user I think no more that 20-30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have your functions defined either manually or programmatically into a list and then you would call that list using the index from `ListView.builder` like this

```
List<Function> itemfunctions = [
        (){print('Button Pressed!');},   
        (){Navigator.of(context).pop()},
        (){Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, NewScreen.routeName)},
    ];
//Where you initialize this depends on whether you need context or not

  ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: numbers.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  numbers[index].toString(),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('$index number'),
                  onPressed: itemfunctions[index],
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
```

Comment: Didn't work for. I click on the items but nothing happens. I'll uptade my code and if your kind to help me please do so

Comment: that is because you are trying to call a function from inside a function

Comment: And I still need the context... where shoul I place the function?

Comment: I changed my code to reflect the changes you need to make if you want to keep that print statement in ``onTap``  you need to get rid of the ``(){}`` in the list you cant have ``(){}`` in both onTap and the ``List``

Comment: if you need context its in the right spot right at the top of your build function

Comment: I won't keep that print. If I don't place the list function insite widget build I get error on context

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212025/discussion-between-luis-fernando-scripcaru-and-wcyankees424).

Comment: accept and upvote answer please if you need more help let me know im happy to help :)

Comment: Yeah I did thank you so much. I left some messages in the chat